Terminate Data read from Serial Port if data not in Right Format
I am using C# to read data from a Serial Port, and was wondering if there was a way to abort reading data from a serial port if it is not in the exact format for example !COM data in is the right format and not #POM data in.
After initializing the serial port I ran this one line:
mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
private void MySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    
        private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Regex reg = new Regex(@"\A!COM");
            var sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            if (reg.IsMatch(indata) is true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Data Received from a COM Port {sp.PortName}:");
            }
            else{
             break;
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine(indata);
        }

If there was a way to stop the process because I am scanning all the COM Ports on a desktop and looking for ports that share this data format. There is an interval of reading data.

Just don't use the data you received.  Beware that you are getting yourself into trouble with this code.  Best thing to do is test with the actual device you need to interface with as soon as possible.  Focus on getting it right first.

@HansPassant How am I getting myself in trouble with this code?
